# Is there anyway we can associate all ticker symbols against the stock exchange they are listed in?

Tags: java, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance, ticker

I've been using Yahoo! Finance API to fetch stock prices. The XML in the links [1](http://www.batstrading.com/market_data/symbol_listing/xml/) and [2](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.industry%20where%20id%20in%20(select%20industry.id%20from%20yahoo.finance.sectors)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys) have a list of most ticker symbols I would need, but they are jumbled and not sorted based on the stock markets they are associated with (for e.g., I would like to associate Google's ticker symbol 'GOOG' against NASDAQ). Given the total number of companies listed in the XML files, it would be extremely time consuming to try and manually associate them against their stock market.

Is there anyway we can achieve this using code (preferably Java) or is there an available site which does that for us? I have been Googling this for the past couple of days but haven't been able to find anything helpful. Please let me know if anymore details are required.

Comment: As I see your links, you will need the list of Nasdaq companies too. And to answer your question : yes you can do it in Java and in most languages ; that's no big deal. You can also create a small DB and insert the different files. What you want to do is just a `join` on 2 tables : `Company` and `Market`.

Comment: @AbbéRésina: I think I get your point, but the links have symbols for companies listed with over 20 different stock markets and in a nice XML format. I have checked lists of NASDAQ companies and for other stock markets too, but couldn't find results in an XML/CSV/JSON format that I can use directly. The lists I found on NASDAQ and other websites would require manual sorting. Sorry if I misunderstood your comment.